# Galois group of extension generated by all cubic roots

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be generated by all cubic roots of rational numbers, that is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\{\sqrt[3]{a}:a\in\mathbb{Q}\})$. I would like to understand its Galois group.

I only could prove that $K/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ has Galois group given by $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (by Kummer theory it corresponds to
$\text{Hom}\left(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)^*/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)^{*3}, \langle\zeta_3\rangle \right)$.
So at least the group has a nice normal subgroup of index two. Can someone continue from here?

Comment: Can you do it if you add a finite number of cubic roots, say, just one?

Comment: You mean the basic example of the splitting field of $x^3-a$? It is always $S_3$.

Comment: And if you add two cubic roots?

Comment: Oh wow! In the finite case it is a semidirect product $\Delta/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)^{*3}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (if I add $a_1,\dots, a_r$ the subgroup $\Delta$ is $<a_1,\dots, a_r>$). I also need to give the automorphism associated to $1\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Say that $a_1,\dots,a_r$ are independent (considering the multiplicative group modulo cubes a $\mathbb{F}_3$-vector space). Then the only involution of $\mathbb{F}_3^r$ that fixes any component (because $a_i\mapsto a_i,a_i\zeta_3,a_i\zeta_3^2$) is the "opposite map" $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: Now the infinite case follows by taking a basis of $\mathbb{F}_3^{\mathbb{N}}$ and passing to the inductive limit (the obvious projections commute because of the description of the semidirect product). So in the end $(\prod_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (and the action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $x\mapsto -x$. Right?